# after 8.6.14 set entity reference field via form alter failed

Tags: forms, hooks

after the core update some how the form alter set field was broken, I tried multiple methods but its not working like :

> $form['field_trip_reference']['widget']['#default_value'] =
>   array(820);
>   $form['field_trip_reference']['widget'][0]['target_id']['#default_value']
>   = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load(820);   $form['field_trip_reference']['widget'][0]['target_id']['#value'] =
>   \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load(820);
>   $form['field_trip_reference']['widget'][0]['target_id']['#default_value']
>   = 820;   $form['field_trip_reference']['widget'][0]['target_id']['#value'] =
>   820;   $form['field_trip_reference']['widget'][0]['target_id'] =
>   \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load(820);
>   $form['field_trip_reference']['widget'][0]['target_id'] = 820;
>   $form['field_trip_reference']['widget']['target_id']['#default_value']
>   = 'node:820';

anything that needs to updated?

UPdate : (its my own mistake) this is the one that is working

```
$form['field_reference']['widget']['#default_value'] = $thenodeid;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out I am overwriting the form and the one that is working for me is :

> $form['field_reference']['widget']['#default_value'] = $thenodeid;